# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel on first request

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, tls1.2, webrequest

When for a first time I am calling an API over https, I get a message

> "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

If I again call the same url, I get the right response.

I use `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
and I wrote `servicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;` 
but the result message was the same

Comment: It seems you added ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; after a call. so the first time you don't have it but the second time as you run that line before, you don't have any problem.

Comment: `servicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;` is unrelated and you probably want it set to `false` anyway. -- When you connect to a `Https` resource, you need - not always but quite probably, to validate the server certificate(s), using [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback) callback. Set that up, too. Last but not least, always have a valid/proper UserAgent header in the request.

Comment: I had the same issue, I've added this code:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
 before  creating RestClient and it 
 works for me.